# Grid View 'date:datetime' gives wrong formatted date time - Yii2

Tags: datetime, gridview, yii2

I have a column named **'date'** in my table. On grid view I'm displaying this field by formatting as  `'date:datetime'`

But this is showing data in grid view with hour incremented by 1 hour.

For example: value in the table is **2016-03-15 09:00:02** and it's output on grid view is **Mar 15, 2016, 10:00:02 AM**. See the hour field is incremented by exactly 1.
Why it is like this?

Comment: check your timezone setting.

Comment: @G4M1TG My timezone is +5:30 Asia/Kolkata and already updated in my script and application.